# Zend Framework: How to redirect as a POST request?

Tags: zend-framework

I need to POST data from inside a controller to a third party website and make sure they receive my website as the HTTP_REFERER. How can I do this?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html should be what your looking for, under advanced usage, look for "Setting Custom Request Headers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Referer is sent as a header, simply:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
$client->setHeaders('Referer', 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/');
$client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

Comment: Awesome. I did not know that it was a header. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no robust way to have the client browser post some data of its own accord with an appropriate HTTP referrer.

You will have to do it from the server, using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or a similar library.

Comment: He was talking about doing it from the server

Comment: @pharalia : the "redirect" in the title made me suspect he wanted to tell the client to do it.